# Using unicode in "like" operator

Tags: sql, sap-ase

In Sybase ASE 15, how can I use unicode to search for records containing a certain character using the like operator? For example, `U+001E`

pseudo-code:

```
select * from table where field like "%{U+001E}%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the collation on your table supports `unicode`.

Use `Nvarchar/Nchar`. There used to be an `Ntext` datatype as well,
but it's depreciated now in favour of `Nvarchar`.

The columns take up twice as much space over the non-unicode counterparts 
(char and varchar).

Then when **manually** inserting into them, use N to indicate it's unicode text:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(SomeNvarcharColumn) VALUES (N'français')
```

Comment: Are you certain that `ntext` is deprecated in Sybase?